# How can I store static class objects for recall on any page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, properties, static

I want to store static values in a class for later use use on any page in the web. The values will be the same for all users.

Page_Init: Retrieve global variables from their respective sources and assign them to their static objects inside the classes within the GlobalStaticVariables class.

I call to set the static values from the MasterPage like so

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Web.StartUp.SetGlobalStaticVariables(this.Page);
}
///Removed most objects for the sake of brevity
public static Info.GlobalStaticVariables SetGlobalStaticVariables(object _this)
{
    Info.GlobalStaticVariables.Some_StringValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Some_StringValue"].ToString();
    Info.GlobalStaticVariables.Database.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
    Info.GlobalStaticVariables.IIS.DomainName = ((Page)_this).Request.Url.Host;
}
///Removed most objects for the sake of brevity
public class Info
{
    public class GlobalStaticVariables
    {
        public static string Some_StringValue { get; set; }
        public class Database
        {
            public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        }
        public class Ldap
        {
            public static List<string> ServerList { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that I should first see if the Session object exists, then create if it doesn't as I have read that sometimes static values can be lost due to appPool recycle, etc.

I figured I should do this from the MasterPage since I have to reference "Session" but I don't know how I would pass the Page object to a property in a class file.

I use the following in the MasterPage to store the current user so I thought that I could do a similar thing with global variables. So far I have been unsuccessful.

```
public MyClass.Users.CurrentUser GetSetCurrentUser
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["CurrentUser"] == null) GetSetCurrentUser = new MyClass.Users.CurrentUser();
        return (MyClass.Users.CurrentUser)Session["CurrentUser"];
    }
    set { Session.Add("CurrentUser", value); }
}
```

With the previous though, I also have to add the following to each page that wants to reference the GetSetCurrentUser property (Master.GetSetCurrentUser ), but I would prefer to avoid this if possible.

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/mp.Master" %>
```

Unfortunately when I tried the same with GlobalStaticVariables no intellisense appeared aside from .Equals, .GetHashCode, .GetType and .ToString.

I want to be able to call the property GlobalStaticVariables from any page for easy access to it's static values.

Perhaps my thought process is flawed in attempting to do it this way, but I can't think of another way. Perhaps I needs to step away from this for awhile and enjoy the holiday, but I can't, I'm on a mission. :-)

Thank-you for you time and suggestions.

Comment: The Master page isn't the correct place for it. What you can do is create your own `BasePage` class that inherits `Web.Page`. Then declare a protected method: `protected MembershipUser GetCurrentUser() { // Get from session }`. And now have your page inherit the `BasePage`.

Comment: I don't reference the membership data store at all, so I am confused by your reply. If I don't initiate the call in the MasterPage then where do I? And I don't see where this would help public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page {}, but I might implementing your vision incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [HttpApplicationState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate(v=vs.110).aspx) that is available in your page by `Context` property which holds an [`Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.application(v=vs.110).aspx)  property.

How you can use it:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     var last = Context.Application["lastActivity"];
     lblLastActivity.Text = last == null?"(none)": ((DateTime) last).ToString();
     Context.Application["lastActivity"] = DateTime.Now;
}
```

One other option is the use of [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache(v=vs.110).aspx) which works similar but objects stored in the Cache can get removed from the cache (to free memory). You  should be able to reload the objects in that case though.